# Illegal conversion from String to System.HttpResponse

Tags: apex, integration, compile-error

I Have the class AnimalLocator and a method getAnimalNameById

```
  HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

    if(response.getStatusCode() == 200){

        Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
        animal = (Map<String, Object>) results.get('animal');

    }

    return (String)animal.get('name');
```

when return the name of animal map 
I get the error "Illegal conversion from String to System.HttpResponse"
this problem it is return line

```
return (String)animal.get('name');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your method is typed as

```
HttpResponse getAnimalNameById()
```

This indicates to Apex that your method returns an `HttpResponse`, but the value you're actually returning is a `String`. The error results because the `String` value cannot be converted to the expected return type for this function.

I believe this is a Trailhead module; if so, please make sure that you are returning the data type that is expected by Trailhead for and that your method is declared with the same return type.

Comment: Yes thank you. When i created the method I put  HttpResponse instead of a String